# How to check to see if a folder is writable by server

Tags: apache, permissions, content-management-system

This page outlines instructions for installing a CMS called Statamic: http://statamic.com/learn/digging-in/installing

> Make sure that the following folders are writable by the server:
>
> - `_cache` — this one’s a must
> - `_logs` — if you want to enable message logging
> - `_content` & `_config/users` — if you want to use the Control Panel

I know this should is really basic, but I don't know anything about how to check the server's write permissions. I'm a front-end guy. Can anyone drill this down for me? Step one... do I need to use Terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact your hosting provider if you don't know about server permissions. I use InMotion Hosting and they're freaking awesome, all the time. Live chat is the best.

For me it was as simple as looking at the folders in my cPanel's File Manager. If I needed to change the permissions, I simply right-clicked it and checked / unchecked the appropriate boxes.

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/how-to/change-file-permissions

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what OS you use, but I will assume it's a *nix based OS.

First make sure the `owner` and `group` of the folders are the web servers user or a group the web server is part of. In some systems the `Apache` user is setup as `www-data` (Can be found in `httpd.conf` as `User` and `Group`). Something like this would do what you want:

```
chown <user>.<group> <your folders>
chmod 744 <your folder>
```

Your really don't need the group in `chown` if you do not want to and using the example with `www-data` it would be:

```
chmod www-data _logs
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using Mac OS X 10.7.5. Sorry but I'm a total server novice here... how do I "make sure the owner and group of the folders are the web servers user or a group the web server is part of" ? From there it sounds like I need to jump in Terminal and work with the command line?

Comment: To check who own the file from the command line type `ls -al <path to parent of your folder>`. If your folder is in `/var/log/_logs` you do `ls -al /var/log` and see who own the folder. And yes, thous are command line commands. They should be valid on OS X since I think it's *BSD based(?). You can probably do this in the OS GUI but I know nothing about OSX GUI. :)